# How would this creatures transition areas look?

Tags: creature-design, shapeshifters

I have been working with a creature in mind for awhile and just cant quite figure out the transition areas. The person changes from a human to a creature form.

Creature Form:
Reddish Gold in Color with a
Jackal Muzel,Serval Ears, Blue Cat Eyes, Huge Eagle Wings with, Feathered Back and Shoulders, Furred Chest and Arms reptilian Scaled Legs and Hips, furry clawed and and reptilian clawed and scaled feet.

What would the areas  where the fur gives way to scales look like? I want to try to get a smooth transition not a stark fur straight to scales appearance but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Looks like you have it pretty well mapped out. What is left?

Comment: How is this related to shapeshifters?

Comment: There are many [pictures](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Minneteppich_KGM.jpg) (and [statues](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:FASTWÜRMS_-_Gryphon.jpg)) of [griffins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griffin) out there. (The creature in the question looks like a "anti" griffin -- normally griffins have lion's *hind* legs and eagle's talons on their *front* legs. But there are [counterexamples](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grifone_(mitologia)#/media/File:Chaos_Monster_and_Sun_God.png).)

Comment: This is the creature form of an otherwise human individual.They shape shift into this form. I'm curious as to the area where the fur would blend in with the scales to make it a more smooth transition would it just be fur starting to come in and a few less scales?

Comment: *"The area where the fur would blend in with the scales":* there is no such area. Have you ever seen a bird? Birds have feathers, and scaly feet (sometimes legs). The transition line is sharp. Or consider [beavers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beaver), who have fur and scaly tails; again, the transition is sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A color wheel of textures** is probably the easiest way to describe it, unless you want just hard lines separating the textures with no merging but then you wouldn't be asking this question.

Anyways, your creature transition areas will probably look like a color wheel, where one color fades into another. Scales would gradually fade to feathers(or whatever textures end up touching) until it's just one left on either side. The overall transition area is up to you. Bigger and smaller creatures probably have proportional sized transition areas based off of whatever your initial size has the transition area be.

Comment: There are millions, billions of creatures on Earth with scales and feathers. Can you give *one* example where a bird's scaly skin on their feet *"fades to"* the feathered skin of the body?

Comment: @AlexP, i dont have to, this is for a fictional world.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b thank you. With this cretuare having reptilian scales and not typical bird leg scales, I believe your answer fits what I was hoping to accomplish.